# Ways to avoid CSS overwrites in Cvent?

Tags: php, html, css

I am attempting to edit CSS classes for an event on a particular event manager tool. Particularly I want to edit the background of a button and make it an image. The issue is, when I put background: url('path/to/image'); cvent inserts a relative path before the URL to the image. Do you all know of any ways I may be able to trick the Cvent compiler to not recognize this string as an image?

Comment: I used inline <style> </style> on the HTML code and it accepted it. Moving with this but no doubt anticipate issues into the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using absolute path like 
url('/path/to/image')
or even the full URL like
url('http://example.com/path/to/image')